# How to know perticular package/application exist in a phonegap application

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I want to know if particular package name say "com.android.abc" exist in my device or not.
I am using Phonegap and I would like to find out how to do this by phonegaps internal javascript functions.

thank in advance

kobi